# How can I fix my code so that it contains both a "save" and "save as" functions?

Tags: java, javafx, save, save-as

I have two buttons in a menubar that contains both a save and save as button. However, I currently have the code for both of them the same and it does the save as currently with prompting the user where they want to save. I want the save button to only save without prompting for the dialog unless the file doesn't yet exist.

I've tried fiddling around with the code to try and figure out a workaround, but have not figure it out.

```
fileMenu.getItems().add(saveItem);
    saveItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            FileChooser saveFile = new FileChooser();
            saveFile.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg"));
            saveFile.setTitle("Save File");

            File file = saveFile.showSaveDialog(stage);
            if (file != null) {
                try {
                    WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage(width, height);
                    canvas.snapshot(null, writableImage);
                    RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImage, null);
                    ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", file);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            }
        }
    });
    fileMenu.getItems().add(saveAsItem);
    saveAsItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            FileChooser saveFile = new FileChooser();
            saveFile.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg"));
            saveFile.setTitle("Save File");

            File file = saveFile.showSaveDialog(stage);
            if (file != null) {
                try {
                    WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage(width, height);
                    canvas.snapshot(null, writableImage);
                    RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImage, null);
                    ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", file);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The code currently does the exact same save function for each save button. I want it to only prompt for the save as button.

Comment: Well, "save" is going to depend on "save as" (or "open"), in that it relies on knowing before hand "where" you're going to save something.  With this in mind, you need to "store" the location somewhere you can access it later (like a manager or something).  Once you have this information, you could write a "saveTo" method which takes a reference to the `File` and performs the actual save operation, this way `save` and `saveAs` only need to call this method and pass in the fore-mentioned `File` reference, either from memory or from the user

Comment: My first recommendation would be to write a `saveTo` method, which took a `File` reference and performed the save operation.  From there, you would need to fill in the requirements for `save` and `saveAs` so that they could obtain a reference to the `File` the user wants to use and pass that to the `saveTo` method

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a File instance field in your class that is initially assigned to null. When you read in a File or when you do your first save, then this field is assigned to that File. When the `save` button is pressed, then you check if the field is null, and if so, show the dialog as you would for the `save-as` button. If the field is *not* null, then you simply write the file to disk using the data that you have and that File.

for example (code not tested):

```
// a private instance field
private File myFile = null;
```

```
fileMenu.getItems().add(saveItem);
saveItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (myFile == null) {
            saveAs();
        } else {
            writeFile(myFile);
        }
    }
});

fileMenu.getItems().add(saveAsItem);
saveAsItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        saveAs();
    }
});
```

```
private void writeFile(File file) {
    if (file != null) {
        try {
            WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage(width, height);
            canvas.snapshot(null, writableImage);
            RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImage, null);
            ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", file);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}

private void saveAs() {
    FileChooser saveFile = new FileChooser();
    saveFile.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg"));
    saveFile.setTitle("Save File");

    File file = saveFile.showSaveDialog(stage);
    myFile = file; // !! 
    writeFile(file);
}
```